# Way to get current edition in build script?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-2018

Is it possible to read the currently used Rust edition in a build script? Maybe through an environment variable?

I tried `EDITION` and `CARGO_EDITION`, but it didn't work. I didn't find any documentation on this either.

Comment: Just print the rust version of compiler should be enough ?

Comment: @Stargateur No, I don't want to know if the compiler supports it, I want to know, if it's enabled.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to read the currently used Rust edition in a build script?

I'm going to ignore your direct question because there isn't a single edition in play and the edition *shouldn't matter*.

**Every crate** in the entire dependency graph chooses which edition it will be compiled with.  If your crate is written to use the 2018 edition, *just your crate* will be compiled using the edition settings. Then, the MIR of all the crates, a version-independent implementation, is stuck together to produce the final result.

If you are writing a library, opting into the 2018 edition is no different than opting into some feature that is only available in a newer version of Rust. Since the 2018 edition went stable in Rust 1.31, that would be the equivalent version.

---

One situation that I can see needing to know the edition is if you are generating code. In that case, I'd advocate for one of:

- only generating code that works in both editions
- your code accepts an argument from the end user that specifies what kind of code to generate.